# So does bitlocker requires me to use password for my computer?

Tags: bitlocker

I still do not quite understand how bitlocker protect my data.

Say I do not require user login to my computer.

Even if I have bitlocker, anyone will just use my computer like usual.

Does bitlocker require password? I was never asked for password.

I am only asked to back up key in USB flash drive and that's it. My computer can run fine without it.

Comment: The point you're missing is that bitlocker encrypts what's stored on the hard drive. With autologin your disk is still encrypted, but everyone is automatically granted access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not requiring a user to login, you have effectively rendered Bitlocker virtually useless.  You need to re-enable the login screen to make use of Bitlocker.  Bitlocker will check the validity of the login and then allow access to the encryted disk.  By auto logging in, the check will always pass.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay. Will login.

Comment: Actually it depends on the key protectors of your Bitlocker VMK, which is the key that is used to decrypt the FVEK. When you're at the login screen, Bitlocker already unlocked the encryption of the system in most cases, but it depends on the key protector you're using.